# How to Parse JSON Data in ReactNative?

Tags: react-native

I have fetch API which is having JSON Data and Getting Json Response,but in JSON Data Format there are two array and i have getting only one arrays response after that not responding,so how to get whole array/JSON data response?

What should I write here to get the value of "Title" in the following Code?

```
componentDidMount() {
return fetch(
  'https://library.booksmeridian.com/cgi-bin/koha/app-scripts/koha-issued_items.pl?borrowernumber=3918')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    this.setState({
        loading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson.Data},
    );
    console.log(responseJson);
  })}
render() {return (
  <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.dataSource}
    renderItem = {({ item}) => (
    <View> <Text>{item.isIssue}</Text></View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    />
  </View>
):}}}
```

I want the output like this:

```
isIssue:True,
DueDate: 13 Mar 2019,
Biblionumber: 61482,
Title: Ramayana Part 12 Lava Kusha Episode Part II,
IssueDate: 13 Mar 2019,
ISBN: 9781730107733,
Barcode: B0157817
```

Comment: What is your console.log(responseJson); result

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
this.setState({
  loading: false,
   dataSource: responseJson.Data
});
```

To this:

```
this.setState({
  loading: false,
   dataSource: responseJson
});

console.log('RESPONSE_JSON', responseJson)
```

Check the console if you are getting the all responses you want. then you can loops through it.

Answer (score 0):

if your JSON look like this your code is true

```
{
  Data:{
     isIssue:True,
     DueDate: 13 Mar 2019,
     Biblionumber: 61482,
     Title: Ramayana Part 12 Lava Kusha Episode Part II,
     IssueDate: 13 Mar 2019,
     ISBN: 9781730107733,
     Barcode: B0157817
    }
}
```

becuse you say this:

```
 dataSource: responseJson.Data
```

if you don't have `Data` and just have json like this:

```
{
isIssue:True,
DueDate: 13 Mar 2019,
Biblionumber: 61482,
Title: Ramayana Part 12 Lava Kusha Episode Part II,
IssueDate: 13 Mar 2019,
ISBN: 9781730107733,
Barcode: B0157817
}
```

you don't need `Data` after  `dataSource: responseJson`

and finally you can use `dataSource` like this:

```
<Text>    {this.state.dataSource.Title}    </Text>
<Text>    {this.state.dataSource.DueDate}  </Text>
```

Comment: But My JSON Like This:

Comment: {
 "Data": [{
  "isIssue": "True"
 }, {
  "Issues": [{
   "DueDate": "13 Mar 2019",
   "Biblionumber": "61482",
   "Title": "Ramayana Part 12 Lava Kusha Episode Part II",
   "IssueDate": "13 Mar 2019",
   "ISBN": "9781730107733",
   "Barcode": "B0157817"
  }]
 }]
}

Comment: and also i use <Text>{this.state.dataSource.Title} </Text>     But i have getting a error like this   "Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN"